# Access denied message on custom B2C login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a MVC application and I use Azure B2C to handle logging and signing in.

In the new portal I have entered a `Custom Page URI`. I can navigate to this URL without problems. I have created a plain `.html` page:

```
<div id="api" data-name="IdpSelections">
    <div class="intro">
        <p>Sign up</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button class="accountButton" id="GoogleExchange">Google+</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="accountButton" id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange">Email</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have placed this html in the root of the project, so it is accessible like this `http://myUrl/SignInPage.html`

In the `web.config` I have added a line to enable CORS:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem is that when this page is supposed to show up, IE shows this error message:

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
>
> We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
>
> Correlation ID:[Some Guid]
>
> Timestamp:2016-04-07 09:21:03Z
>
> AADB2C90065: A B2C client-side error 'Access is denied. ' has occurred requesting the remote resource.

What can I do this get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just referring to the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization/#the-page-ui-customization-feature), the key requirements are as follows:

- Div element with the ID of api.
- CORS header in place.
- Access via HTTPS.

I can see you have the `div` element in correctly and the header in place, but not sure about HTTPS access. A great tool for getting this setup is linked from the documentation and can be found on the official Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool/).

I would also check your header, you are sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, however this is a response header, confirm this is the correct header to be using. Valid request and response headers are on the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) website.

The only request headers I can see are listed here:

- Origin
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Headers

Comment: I was testing it with localhost, without https, so I've published my site to azure and supplied the https address of my app as the custom page url.

Comment: There was a time when AD B2C would allow HTTP redirects. That is no longer the case.